# cannot create temp file - No Space left on device

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I have some problems running some commands, the console gives me:
*

> bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on
>   device

```
roo@Server: df -h
    Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev                       991M  4.0K  991M   1% /dev
    tmpfs                      201M  408K  200M   1% /run
    /dev/disk/by-label/DOROOT   40G   20G   18G  54% /
    none                       4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    none                       5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    none                      1001M     0 1001M   0% /run/shm
    none                       100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

I search and verify, the Inodes is full 100%:

```
root@Server: df -i
Filesystem                 Inodes   IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                       253531     402 253129    1% /dev
tmpfs                      256244     339 255905    1% /run
/dev/disk/by-label/DOROOT 2621440 2620484    956  100% /
none                       256244       2 256242    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                       256244       1 256243    1% /run/lock
none                       256244       1 256243    1% /run/shm
none                       256244       3 256241    1% /run/user
```

How i delete the right files, is secure delete inodes files? 
I researched on the Internet several commands to delete, but I'm not sure if it will delete system files / useful files.

```
root@Server:   for i in /*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
/lib
11347
/proc
66820
/root
115
/run
338
/sbin
180
/sys
20920
/tmp
1
/usr
198764
/var
2407447
```

How i fix this problem?

Comment: 2.5 million files in `/var/` appears to be  lot, descend into that directory and find out which application/process is creating those files.

Comment: Ahmm! the problem is /var/lib/php5/ 
with 2401455, how i fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205796/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @HBrujn suggest, i search by big files:

```
for i in /var/lib/*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
```

I noticed were the session files from php5

```
/var/lib/php5/
```

Where i run this code to remove the old sessions file (+1 day)

```
now=$(date +%s); time for i in /var/lib/php5/sess_5*; do if ((($(stat "$i" -c '%Z') + (86400 )) < $now)); then rm -fv $i; fi; done
```